# How to keep a list on a single line with the first item to display ellipsis if text overflow?

Tags: css

I have a list of items:

- User Name
- Login
- Sign Up

to be displayed on a single line. Example:

```
->     John Doe  Login  Sign Up <-
```

On a browser with a narrow display, the user name may be too long, causing the line to break. Instead of breaking, I want the user name to be compacted showing ellipsis if the text causes a line break. Example:

```
-> Benjamin F... Login  Sign Up <-
```

How can this be done with CSS?

**jsFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6fSB/)**

Comment: Please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, please wait a moment. I will post it up.

Answer (score 3):

Use `width` or `max-width` (independently or together):

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap; /* forces single-line display */
}

li {
    /* existing CSS in which I assume you've defined widths and such */
    float: left;
    width: 5em;
}

li:first-child {
    max-width: 6em;
    overflow: hidden; /* for browsers that don't support the next rule */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nXCPG/2/).

Comment: I think it's possible *without* having to hard-code a max width. There is the `ellipsis` value for `text-overflow`.

Comment: The browser width is a variable, @ŠimeVidas, yes, I am looking to use that CSS function.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow I can't help you if you don't post your HTML/CSS code.

Comment: @Šime: well, I guess `width` and `max-width` could both be used (independently of each other, or together). But at least one of the two is required, I think.

Comment: @DavidThomas, the width of `li` should be free, not fixed. Can you take a look at the jsFiddle in my updated question? Thanks.

Comment: @Question: an `li` element (like others) will, without constraints, expand as necessary to contain its contents; if there's no constraint there's no overflow.

Comment: @DavidThomas, I am not sure. So does it mean that what I want couldn't be achieved with CSS?

Comment: I can't think of a way to, essentially, simulate a maximum width without using `width` or `max-width`; it might be possible to do something with JavaScript that'll add, remove or otherwise change, classes or presentation. But it depends on where the dynamic `li` is coming from, I suppose.

Comment: Your concern it quite valid, I will think about this and keep trying. Anyway thanks for your help. I will leave this question open for a while :)